# Microsoft Teams - lags on linux

Tags: microsoft

**HI There**

I have a problem with using my teams on linux. When i want to change my overlap team i have big lag. I tried everything to fix it from change bios settings to change linux distro. Nothing helps me, so i was forced to write a message here. I noticed that only one core works at 100%.

Here is my computer specs:

- Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile
- Ram 16 GB
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Gnome 64-bit

If anyone knows how to help me, please write it down.

I will be grateful.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the answer to how to deal with this issue, but rather advice on how to approach seeking answer to it.

Note that Microsoft Teams on Linux is in Preview mode. That is, it's not the final stable version of the software yet, so there are bound to be bugs. Since it's proprietary software, meaning the Linux community can't check its code to see what's causing the bug, the more suitable place to post your question would be on Microsoft support. So try to post your question there as well. You may get more relevant answers.

You can also try Microsoft Teams Insiders package - this one should be more up-to-date and even less stable, but it might just be so that this package solves your problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by my mouse, i changed it and all work correctly.

I used before Lenovo precision mouse.